# Communication between objects in C# issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, windows-phone

I'm trying to provide communication between two objects that can be best described as turn - based. What I mean by that is that the first object(a Game class) has multiple goals which are specified in a database, and the second object represents a class that is used to play animations from sprite sheets. My goal currently is to show an introductory animation in the Game class(that I have done), show the player his first goal. Then the class expects user input in the form of animation parameters which are then passed as a list to be animated. 
Once the animation is complete, I check if the goal is met. If it is met, and it is not the last one, I need to go back to the Game class, show the next goal, play a sort off explanation, then expect user input and this repeats until all goals are satisfied.

This is Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.

Here is the code of the Game class(most relevant snippets):

```
 public Game(GamePage gp, int chapterNum)
   {
       currentClickedCommand = null;
       currentClickedSlot = null;
       gamePage = gp;
       chapterNumber = chapterNum;
       isAnimationComplete = false;
       //chosenCommands = new string[5];
       gamePage.characterRectangle.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
       Thread AnimationThread = new Thread(playIntroAnimation);
       AnimationThread.Start();
       Thread loadingThread = new Thread(loadControls);
       loadingThread.Start();
   }
```

These two threads are used to play the animation(animation thread), and the other one waits for a static variable to be set to true to load user input controls. The code:

```
private void loadControls()
       {
           while (!InformationObject.isSequenceComplete) { }
           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
           {
              // loadGoals();
               showCurrentGoal();
               gamePage.CommandGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
               gamePage.SlotGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
               gamePage.mainCanvas.Background = null;
               gamePage.characterRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
               loadCommands();
               loadSlots();
           });
       }
```

This is the method which plays the animation sequence that the user selected:

```
public void AnimateCurrentAnimationInSequence(Rectangle container) {
            AnimationParams currentParams = sequenceToAnimate[currentAnimationInSequence];
            DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            if (sequencePlayerInteractions.Count != 0 && sequencePlayerInteractions != null)
            {
                PlayerInteraction currentInteraction = sequencePlayerInteractions[CurrentInteraction];
                TalkBubble interactionBubble = new TalkBubble(currentInteraction.Value);
                interactionBubble.setWidthHeight((int)container.Width, (int)container.Height);
                talkBubble = interactionBubble;
                onCanvas.Children.Add(talkBubble);
                Canvas.SetLeft(talkBubble, Canvas.GetLeft(container) + 30);
                Canvas.SetTop(talkBubble, Canvas.GetTop(container) + 30);
            }

            // ovdje razdvojiti po tipu
            if (!currentParams.IsMoveType)
            {
                ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush() { Stretch = Stretch.None, AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left, AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top };
                imageBrush.Transform = new CompositeTransform();
                imageBrush.ImageSource = currentParams.Sheet;
                container = setRectangleProperties(container, currentParams.Width, currentParams.Height, imageBrush);

                // Storyboard za animaciju
                Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                if (currentParams.Loop) sb.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever; // odredjujem da li je na repeat

                // Animacija za talk bubble
                if (sequencePlayerInteractions.Count != 0 && sequencePlayerInteractions != null)
                {
                    fadeInAnimation.From = 0.0;
                    fadeInAnimation.To = 1.0;
                    fadeInAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(fadeIn_complete);
                    fadeInAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
                    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
                    Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, talkBubble);
                }

                // Animacija sheeta preko frameova
                int time = 0; // vrijeme kojim odredjujem trajanja frameova    
                ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames frm = createFrames(currentParams.Repetitions, time, currentParams.Width, currentParams.NumberOfFrames); // inicijaliziram frameove animacije sheeta                
                frm.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
                fadeInAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);
                Storyboard.SetTarget(frm, container.Fill);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(frm, new PropertyPath("(ImageBrush.Transform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));
                sb.Children.Add(frm);
                if (sequencePlayerInteractions.Count != 0 && sequencePlayerInteractions != null) sb.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);
                sb.Completed += new EventHandler(animationInSequence_Complete);
                sb.Begin();
            }
            else {
                cameFromSequenceAnimate = true;
                AnimateMove(container, currentParams.Direction, currentParams.Steps);
            }
        }

        private void animationInSequence_Complete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(currentAnimationInSequence + 1 == animationCount))
            {
                if (sequencePlayerInteractions.Count != 0 && sequencePlayerInteractions != null) { if (!(CurrentInteraction + 1 == interactionCount)) CurrentInteraction++; }
                currentAnimationInSequence++;
                AnimateCurrentAnimationInSequence(currentContainer);
            }
            else
            {
                // Goal satisfaction 
                if (CurrentCommandIDs != null && CurrentCommandIDs.Count != 0)
                {
                    bool has = true;
                    List<string> sequenceID = new List<string>();
                    foreach (AnimationParams ap in sequenceToAnimate) sequenceID.Add(ap.AnimationID);
                    for (int i = 0; i < CurrentCommandIDs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!sequenceID.Contains(CurrentCommandIDs[i])) has = false;
                    }
                    if (has) { InformationObject.isCriteriaMet = true;
                               InformationObject.setCurrentGoal(InformationObject.currentGoal + 1);
                    }
                    else InformationObject.isCriteriaMet = false;
                }
                KidCode.Game.isSequenceComplete = true;
                InformationObject.isSequenceComplete = true;
                currentAnimationInSequence = 0;
                CurrentInteraction = 0;

            }
        }
```

Now, after the animation is done, I need to somehow return back to the game class to basically repeat this. I tried using a static class(InformationObject)
to store information about current goals but I wasn't able to utilize it

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's many thing that are terribly wrong with your code. For starters, the `while (!InformationObject.isSequenceComplete) { }` will fully occupy a CPU core, for no reason at all. When waiting, try using either Tasks or mutexes (such as ManualResetEvent). Then, what the point of waiting in `loadControls` if in the end you delegate the work to the UI thread? (using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`). To me, the method setting `isSequenceComplete` to true should be the one making the call to the dispatcher. I think your code is needlessly complex, you should rethink it  using `Task` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, can you give some advice on the communication issue?